Is there a way to permanently remove glitched flowing water blocks in the End?
There is a known bug (reported here and here) where flowing water doesn't dissipate like it should when it reaches y=0 in the End dimension. I'm not asking about the bug itself, only how to remove the unwanted blocks permanently from the affected world.
This Reddit thread suggested flying close enough to the flowing water might cause it to update and disappear, but that didn't happen.
With /gamerule showcoordinates true, I found the exact location of the problem blocks, and used /fill to replace all blocks in the region with air. This appeared to work, since the water disappeared.
However, when I exited the world and then reopened it, they were back again. I tried deleting them with /fill a second time, it seemed to work, but the same thing happened the next time I exited/re-launched the world.
I also tried pouring another bucket of water so that it flowed into the same area, to see if it would cause the glitched blocks to update, but this also didn't work, only added more 'stuck' flowing water blocks to the puddle.
Is there any way to get rid of these blocks permanently?
The issue is affecting a regular Bedrock 1.20.81 world (not a realm or server).
